# Can and should I run 2 versions of XCode side-by-side?

Tags: iphone, configuration, ide, ipad, conflict

Is it possible to install the beta iPhone SDK as well as the latest "official release"?

Is this even necessary, or can i just use the beta for iPhone/iPod development as well as iPad dev?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can i just use the beta for iPhone/iPod development as well as iPad dev?

Yes. The 3.2 SDK contains 3.1, 3.0 and 2.x SDKs. But make sure you switch to one of those when submitting your app to iPhone AppStore.

Answer (score 3):

I believe Apple recommends that you NOT submit to the AppStore using the Xcode betas on the developer site, even if you use the 3.1x SDK. However, you can install both the beta and current versions of Xcode; just select a different directory to install to when installing the beta (for example, /DeveloperBeta).

Comment: +1 for alternate solution. Yes, I did see that Apple recommendation. That's why I asked about the side-by-side install.